Wong's "Introduction to Classical and Quantum Computing" Exercise 7.20
I am currently working my way through "Introduction to Classical and Quantum Computing" by Thomas Wong. I am trying to solve the following problem on Simon's Algorithm:
Exercise 7.20. You are using Simon’s algorithm to find an n = 3 bit string s = $s_2s_1s_0$. You run the
quantum circuit three times, and you get the following values for |z⟩, such that $s · z = 0 \text{ mod } 2$:
|001⟩, |110⟩, |111⟩,
What is $s$?
I am have issues arriving to the same answer as the book. The book says that $s$ = 110. However, I keep getting an answer that indicates that system of equations generated by the circuit is not linearly independent.
The system I get is below:
$0 \cdot s_2 + 0 \cdot s_1 + 1 \cdot s_0 = 0$ mod2
$1 \cdot s_2 + 1 \cdot s_1 + 0 \cdot s_0 = 0$ mod2
$1 \cdot s_2 + 1 \cdot s_1 + 1 \cdot s_0 = 0$ mod2
And I get s1 = 0, and s2 = -s1. I know I am missing something, but I cannot figure out what or why. Any explanation helps.

From what you wrote,
$s_0=0$
$s_2=-s_1$
If $s_1 = 1$ then $s_2=1$. In this case, s = 110
If $s_1 = 0$ then $s_2=0$ In this case, s is a trivial answer
Hence s = 110.
When s has n unknowns, such as $s_0, s_1, .. s_n-1$ then we can have 2 solutions, one is S=0, which is a trivial answer, and the other is what you want, after measuring a linearly independent z n-1 times.

Thank you for answering my question. Makes sense. So if I understand correctly, S = 0 will always be a solution, but we do not care about that, and the other solution is what matters. Though I am still a bit confused about why \ s1 =1 and s2 = 1. Given the way I solved things, if s1 = 1, then s2 = -1. If s2 is -1, do we just say it is 1? I understand from a high level perspective why s1 = 1 and s2 = 1, I am just a bit confused on the specific method to get there.

Yes, since -1 is congruent to 1 mod 2 you can say it is 1.
